# Insert DLookup values into table

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have two tables, tblMaster and Software.

Is there a way in MS Access vba to do DLookup on tblMaster.Title to find the Software Titles in Software and insert the values in tblMaster.Software Title?

**tblMaster**

```
|ID|Title                           |type|state|Software Title|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Adobe Reader                    |A   |Close|
|2 |Apache HTTP Server              |A   |Close|
|3 |Multiple Mozilla Products       |A   |Open |
|4 |Microsoft Windows File Handling |A   |Open |
|5 |Microsoft Windows Client Server |A   |Open |
|6 |HP Printer                      |A   |Open |
|7 |Adobe Acrobat                   |A   |Close|
```

**Software**

```
|SWID|Software Title    |location|
----------------------------------
|1   |Adobe             |1|
|2   |Apache            |1|
|3   |Mozilla           |1|
|4   |Microsoft Windows |2|
|5   |HP                |3|
```

I would like tblMaster to look like this after the DLookup:

**tblMaster**

```
|ID|Title                           |type|state|SWID|Software Title|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Adobe Reader                    |A   |Close|1   |Adobe
|2 |Apache HTTP Server              |A   |Close|2   |Apache
|3 |Multiple Mozilla Products       |A   |Open |3   |Mozilla
|4 |Microsoft Windows File Handling |A   |Open |4   |Microsoft Windows
|5 |Microsoft Windows Client Server |A   |Open |4   |Microsoft Windows
|6 |HP Printer                      |A   |Open |5   |HP
|7 |Adobe Acrobat                   |A   |Close|1   |Adobe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query might get what you want. Should probably just save the software ID into tblMaster then build queries that join the two tables to pull the title.

`UPDATE tblMaster Set SoftwareID = DLookUp("SWID","Software","InStr('" & [Title] & "', [Software Title])>0");`

Comment: Hey @June7 thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but access is saying it didn't update due to validation rule violation.

Comment: Well, it works in my test. So there is something else about your table structure that I don't know. Did you add the SoftwareID number type field to tblMaster?

Comment: So sorry youre right, type is required. And I did add SoftwareID number type field to tblMaster.

Comment: Actually, since this is an UPDATE action, the required parameter is irrelevant. You must have read my comment before I deleted that statement. So still cannot explain why your effort fails and mine succeeds.